# COPY FROM skips column erroneously

Tags: postgresql

I have a file called *data.txt* with the following content:

```
1#1#658#debug#v3##h1#
```

I want to import in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE fields (a int8,
                    b int2, 
                    c int8, 
                    d text, 
                    e text,
                    f int,
                    g text
);
```

I tried to use the COPY command as follows:

```
COPY fields(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) FROM 'data.txt' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER '#', NULL '')
COPY fields(a,b,c,d,e,f,g) FROM 'data.txt' WITH (FORMAT CSV, DELIMITER '#')
```

In both the DBMS tries to insert 'h1' (which is for column *g*) into column *f*, ignoring the NULL value for *f* and producing errors of type:

```
column "f" is of type int but expression is of type text
```

Am I missing any option in the COPY command? Do you have any idea about it?

I am using PostgreSQL version 13.2.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce this here, also on v13.2

```
richard=> \copy fields from data1.txt with (format csv, delimiter '#')
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY fields, line 1: "1#1#658#debug#v3##h1#"
richard=> \copy fields from data1.txt with (format csv, delimiter '#', null '')
ERROR:  extra data after last expected column
CONTEXT:  COPY fields, line 1: "1#1#658#debug#v3##h1#"
```

That is what I would expect, since you have more "#" delimiters than columns.

```
richard=> ALTER TABLE fields ADD COLUMN h text;
ALTER TABLE
richard=> \copy fields from data1.txt with (format csv, delimiter '#', null '')
richard=> SELECT * FROM fields;
 a | b |  c  |   d   | e  | f | g  | h 
---+---+-----+-------+----+---+----+---
 1 | 1 | 658 | debug | v3 |   | h1 | 
(1 row)
```

I've spent hours struggling with strange behaviour like this myself and it has always turned out to be one of two things:

1. The file's contents weren't what I thought they were.
2. I wasn't loading the file I thought I was.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the time you spent on this!
Yes, you are right, I re-checked the structure of the file and it was wrong. It's incredible how I didn't realise it after running many tests!